# Deconstructing type in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types

I have a data type:
`data Days = Mon Int | Tue Int | Wed Int | Thu Int | Fri Int`

The problem is I have no idea how to deconstruct it.

For example I need a function that returns a list where the argument is not 0 e.g:
`[(Mon 1), (Tue 0), (Wed 2), (Wed 0), (Thu 0)]` it should return: `[(Mon 1),(Wed 2)]`

Comment: What does the int value mean here?

Comment: This is just an example, doesnt mean anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to write a "deconstruction function"

```
numberOfDay :: Days -> Int
numberOfDay (Mon v) = v
numberOfDay (Tue v) = v
-- and so on.

days = [(Mon 1), (Tue 0), (Wed 2), (Wed 0), (Thu 0)]
filtered = filter ((/= 0) . numberOfDay) days
```

After all, you could come in at any time and add another constructor that has, for example no arguments. Any mechanism that generically deconstructs a type where all constructors have the same argument list would fail at this point.

Another solution would be, to structure your code slightly different:

```
data Days = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri
data DayVal = DayVal Days Int
```

Comment: @Neil Note that if you forget to handle some case your program will crash at runtime, which is bad. To prevent that, I'd recommend to compile with warnings on (`-Wall` flag) so that GHC complains at compile time about the missing cases.